# How can I delete a malformed row from cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I inserted a row with a malformed column into cassandra (not sure why the update was allowed through). Now, when I execute "select * from keyspace.table;" I get 96 valid rows and one:

```
Failed to decode value ',\xc9\xcc\xb7b!L\xcb\x83\x87\xf2+j\x1b5M' (for column 'id') as bigint: unpack requires a string argument of length 8
```

Is there a way to delete just this row? Note that there is a duplicate row that is identical except not corrupt in that column, so I can just delete all rows that match the other columns without manually reinserting. Is there a simple way to just delete corrupted rows?